# Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

On my heroku I get error

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
2016-04-14T09:25:04.155091+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users         /registrations_controller.rb:123:in `send_confirmation_email'
2016-04-14T09:25:04.155092+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:49:in `daycare'
```

I also add addon `Redis to go`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Redis installed. I know you said you got this on Heroku, but for example, if you were on a Mac and were using Homebrew, you could simply run `brew install redis`, and you'd be good to go. (It fixed it for me, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Your application should not try to connect to the localhost. Instead, your initializer should fetch the env var (`REDIS_URL` IIRC) and use it if it exists.

Comment: I set uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri) in redis.rb  but same error :?

Comment: Is that env var defined for your app?